# SMPS voltage drop in 230v ac to 5v dc flyback

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

I am building a SMPS circuit from a switching IC. This IC has feedback and enable pins for timing and current calculations respectively.

[image: SMPS Circuit]

Transformer Data: (10 pin 1-5, 6-10)
primary: 1-3 - 60 turns, 3-2 25 turns (1-2 is total coil with 1.5 mH)
secondary: 6-10 - 7 turns
aux: 4-5 - 21 turns

When this circuit is operated in open mode (without load), it gives 5.2V (which is what i need). But when we start connecting load, voltage drops a little up to around 4.8V for some 1.4 A or 1.5 A need (10 ohm 10 W resisters in parallel to make load). If i take total parallel load up to 2.5 ohm, it should ideally give 2A at 5V. But happens is voltage start decreasing to 3 V as current raises to 2 A.

Why is that?

(I have tried using 2 1R0 or 2R2 instead of 2 1R5 for cs/enable but with no result, Also using 10 ohm in feedback after diode instead of 1 ohm)

IC: [CT5503s](https://www.icti.in/datasheets/CT5503S.pdf)

EDIT: Updated circuit Image

Comment: can you rewrite the second paragraph is very difficult to understand what is happening.And please attach the IC datasheet

Comment: corrected few details

Comment: Probably the core approaches to the saturation point as the load current increases. Does the core of the transformer (actually, it's a coupled inductor) have air gap?

Comment: I do not know how to know that. We built transformer from data given by supplier. We used ferrite core EE 16/8/5.

Comment: Where in the device data sheet does it tell you that you can expect a perfectly regulated 5 volts with a 2 amp load? Try adding another 10 uF capacitor after the bridge - the example circuit in the data sheet does have two.

Comment: We used there pcb which gives 5V upto 2.1A regulated. But its not working in our custom pcb with same circuit with some transformer and component company changes.

Comment: So, post there circuit.

Comment: As i said, its same circuit with only pcb design and transformer changed from theirs. The above is our transformer details, they gave number of turns data.

Comment: With primary side feedback you are down to the parasitic of your circuit, so some voltage drop is uninvadable. What is your inductance in each winding, leakage inductance seen from the primary and winding resistance of your transformer?

Comment: Some (0.2-0.4 V) is ok, but it is 2V drop.
Primary side: 1.3 mH, 1.09E
secondary side: 11.5 uH
Auxiliary side: 95 uH, 0.3E

Comment: What's E? Ohm? What's your leakage inductance? Enter your values into a circuit simulator like LTspice and observe what happens.

Comment: yes, E is ohm. I will try to find out other details.

Comment: Maybe you can check if your is saturating. Take a current probe and see (and/or measure core temperature at this full load with thermal camera). during Ton you should see the current in the inductor rise linearly, compare waveform with no-load.

Comment: Is there a way to check saturation without thermal camera? Some calculations or using a meter?

Comment: current probe ? Alternatively the voltage across  Rc, but this will be to noisy to measure. And yes you can find example of the calculations online.

Comment: Your updated schematic flipped the secondary winding 180 degrees. Which is it?

Comment: It was problem in schematic. Transformer was correct only. It was saturation problem only i think. I am getting new transformer developed with better core to check.

Answer (score 1):

You have the output (secondary) of the transformer's phase reversed.

Comment: Thats in diagram i guess, in real it's 180 degree. Any way to recheck that?

Comment: @Akshit That ”diagram” and “guess” is a problem to combine in one sentence. If you don’t show 100 % correlation between your schematic diagram with your built circuit, you will have a bad time getting help here, or anywhere else. EEs talk in the language of schematics.